# you should make your bed after you wake up (or say: after you woke up)? A dilemma in expressing the idea

Tags: grammar, tense

Ok, A should say:

1. **you should make your bed after you wake up.**

or

2. **you should make your bed after you woke up.**

In case 1, the waking-up action happened before "make the bed", but English doesn't have "past in the future" tense though we do have "future in the past" tense (was going to do....)

In case 2, you broke the universe because the "waking up" action did not exist at the time of saying.

Comment: As an alternative, you should probably make your bed after you get out of it. Often getting out of bed is better after you have woken up (perfect).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that *woke* is the past tense of *wake*.

> I **woke** up yesterday,

is the past tense of:

> I **wake** up everyday at 6:30,

or

> I *will* **wake** up tomorrow at 6:30